# C# WebBrowser Navigate to File Path fails (file exists)

Tags: c#, navigation, browser

I have a web browser in C# that I want to make navigate to a path (html file) on my local pc.
I tried using this:

```
if (File.Exists(Path + b.HTML))
                {
                    browserCom1.Navigate(Path + b.HTML);
                }
```

The file Exists, but the browser is keep opening an error of Internet Explorer: "cannot find file:///(my path here)"

It is weird because the file is correct. for example if I use:

```
System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog browseFile = new   
System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
  browseFile.ShowDialog();
  String path = browseFile.FileName;
  browserCom1.Navigate(path);
```

and I select the same file that it tried navigating to before, it works.

If I print the above brwseFile File Name to Console(which is the same as my Path+b.HTML by the way), and copy-paste it into the Navigate(...) Function (changing each '\' to '//') it Doesn't work.

I have no Idea what to do. 
I tried something else like:

```
String path=(File.Open(Path + b.HTML, FileMode.Open).Name);
browserCom1.Navigate(path);
```

but the application keep getting freezed upon this.

I also tried with `new URI(path)` and all.

How can I simpley navigate to a HTML file on my computer?

Comment: Does the account under which the application is running have permissions to the folder the file is located in?

Comment: IIRC you can only Navigate to an Url after the current document has been constructed handling some event. The WebBrowser component works just strange.

Comment: I tried hardcoded value. I also mentiond it in the above. C://KioskWpf//WpfApplication2//Images//stuff.html this is the link.

Comment: Yes you are right, i try this as you said and the path is ok. Funny that FileExists and Image excepts this path and browser is not. I changed it thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

You have http slashes, but should have file system slashes, like c:\something\something.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Resolved when I cleaned for double \\ in the code.
If that's not your problem - your problem may be some else problem related to parsing from string to uri.
my path was like this: c:\users\someone1\\myFolder\protocol.htm